Error:AccountNotFound with anchor deploy
hello when I write 'anchor deploy' in terminal, the result is
Deploying cluster: http://127.0.0.1:8899
Upgrade authority: /home/leejinho/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "voting"...
Program path: /home/leejinho/temp/voting-dapp/anchor/target/deploy/voting.so...
Error: AccountNotFound: pubkey=9rJWSuGiNDhH6RHRjAVXCggc5HabfbW1ckPk6k2VYMV1: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
in here, how can I solve 'Error: AccountNotFound blabla'?
Thank you

Since you're trying to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8899, I'm assuming you're trying to deploy to a local test network. Be sure to start up a test validator first.
You can do this by running solana-test-validator in a separate window before running your anchor deploy command.
